# "Mille milles" ?

Tags: expressions

I've been reading *Le Petit Prince* and I came across this sentence early on:

> Il n’avait en rien l’apparence d’un enfant perdu au
> milieu du désert, à mille milles de toute région habitée.

I checked 3 dictionaries and none of them list "mille" as a unit of measurement, so I have to interpret this as some kind of figurative expression - a thousand thousands from any inhabited region? Is this a common expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a unit of measurement. If you search for "*mille*" as a noun, you'll find it in any dictionary. Here's the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mille#Nom_commun_2).

There are several units called "*mille*" but in this context it's most likely a nautical mile. According to [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit%C3%A9s_en_aviation), aviation uses nautical miles for distances, internationally, as well as feet (*pieds*) for altitude and knots (*nœuds*) for speed.

Comment: +1, the nautical mile has not a specific English origin. It corresponds to 1 minute latitude, i.e 60 NM = 1 degree (and 1 knot = 1 NM/hour).

Comment: dang how come it's not in larousse? am i using this thing wrong somehow? https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mille/51453

Comment: @temporary_user_name It is in Larousse https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mille/51452 but it's listed as a homonym for some reason. At the bottom of the page you can find every word sorted alphabetically and there's *mille* twice. I guess Larousse chose to allow multiple entries for exact homographs